What are Terminal 15 and terminal R are why are they named this way?
Resetting values on a car via de odbII port requires sometimes to set the terminals 15 or R in certain position. I've only found on a forum entry online that:
Terminal 15 is accessory (aka position 1 on ignition switch, 0 being the key inserted position)
Terminal R is "running" (aka position 2 on ignition switch).
Can anyone validate this info and if possible provide some reference/ background literature on the numbering approach?

Why were they named this? Because Q and 14 were taken already? Really, I think you'd have to ask the BMW engineer who designed it, but maybe someone knows.
